# EditText in PreferenceScreen and DialogPreference containing PreferenceScreen/CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, android-edittext, preference, preferencescreen, checkboxpreference

I have an application, where I want there to be several EditTexts on one screen, and then to the right of each, a button that will open a dialog for settings related to that EditText

Issue is, I am trying to do this within a PreferenceActivity.
I know I could just use a preference as a button to open a normal Activity to display the linearlayout (or relativelayout), but that really doesn't satisfy what I need.

I can use an EditTextPrefence in the preferenceActivity, but that's really not preferred (it will work if it has to), and I could just use a DialogPreference with checkboxes in it, but I really like the summary capability of a CheckBoxPreference, so I would rather have a dialogpreference that opens and then shows a PreferenceScreen of CheckboxPreferences.

So, I just need an EditText within a preferenceScreen and a CheckBoxPreference within a DialogPreference

It doesn't seem like this is possible, but if so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Issue is, I am trying to do this within a PreferenceActivity.

Since it would appear that these are not preferences, please create a regular activity, using `EditText` and `CheckBox` widgets. Then, you can design it pretty much however you want.

If, OTOH, these are indeed preferences, then please use the standard Android preference UI, which does not resemble what you are describing. The point behind the standard Android preference UI is for it to be *standard*, with minor customizations (e.g., creating some sort of color-picker DialogPreference). Your changes do not sound minor.

Comment: I figured that was the only solution, but in the situation I'm using it for, I will likely stick with a slightly less attractive edittextpreference and checkboxpreference method, because the summary capabilities of the preferences fit my needs.